# nullPointerException with enums

Tags: java

I'm coding a game where the player has to type something in the dialog field, and java has to interpret it as an action. I have a class named GameEngine where i use a switch :

```
public void interpretCommand(final String commandLine) 
{
    Command command = parser.getCommand(commandLine);
    CommandWord commandWord = command.getCommandWord();
    switch ( commandWord ) {
      case UNKNOWN: 
         gui.println("Unknown command...");
         return;
      case LOAD: 
         load(); 
         break;
    } 
}
```

Enums used here are in an enumclass :

```
public enum CommandWord
{
    LOAD("charger"),UNKNOWN("?");
    private String commandWord;
 }
```

and finally, the CommandWords class :

```
public class CommandWords
{
    // a HashMap that holds all valid command words
   private HashMap<String, CommandWord> validCommands; 

   public CommandWords()
   {
      validCommands = new HashMap<String, CommandWord>();
      for(CommandWord command : CommandWord.values()) {
          if(command != CommandWord.UNKNOWN){
              validCommands.put(command.toString(), command);
          }
      }
   }


   /**
     * @param commandWord the command word to look for in the valid commands
     * @return the commandWord associated with the word typed
     */
    public CommandWord getCommandWord(final String commandWord)
    {
        CommandWord command =validCommands.get(commandWord);
        if(command !=null) {
           return command;
        }
        else {
           return CommandWord.UNKNOWN;
        }
    }
```

the Command class :

```
public class Command
{
    private CommandWord commandWord;

    /**
     * @param commandWord from enum class
     */
    public Command(CommandWord commandWord)
    {
        this.commandWord = commandWord;
    }

    public CommandWord getCommandWord()
    {
        return commandWord;
    }
}
```

My problem is very simple: when I type charger, it works, but when I type a random word, not in the list, I get a `NullPointerException` in terminal at the line

```
        switch ( commandWord )
```

in interpretCommand.

I can't see what's wrong with my code. If someone could help, thank you.
Please don't blame me, I'm a novice, I just started a few months ago!

Solution : in command modify/add these lines

```
    public boolean isUnknown()
{
    return (commandWord == null);
}

    public CommandWord getCommandWord()
{
    if(!isUnknown()){

    return commandWord;

}
 else return CommandWord.UNKNOWN;
}
```

Comment: At what line and expression does the NPE occur?

Comment: at the line "switch ( commandWord )"

Comment: You haven't shown your `Command` class. It would be really helpful if you'd show a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: you're right. I just edited.

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need to store the enumeration constants in a map. You can use the generated `valueOf(String)` method that is generated for each enum type. This throws an instance of IllegalArgumentException if you pass an invalid string, but your `getCommandWord` method could intercept that and return something meaningful.

Comment: I suggest adding a test for null in the constructor for `Command`, to ensure the command word is non-null.

Comment: Can you post the parser code?

Comment: @NathanD.Ryan THANK YOU ! I just made a test and now it works !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one thing that can be null at this line and that is `commandWord`. So your method call `command.getCommandWord()` returns null.

EDIT: With the information you have provided now, this means that the parser gives back a `Command` object which has no commandWord set.